# how to fit dropdown till last position of text-field in react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, dropdown

in my code ,  dropdown shown when user type $ symbol ,this is working good till you gave 22 character's I wanted to when user gave more character that dropdown should be set at last position but now dropdown is going to out of the frame of text field ,so how to fix that the dropdown should move relative to the cursor on the current text only?[image]

this should be the last position if user give more than 22 characters but now I am facing problem if i gave more than 22 characters and type $ symbol[image]

```
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [cursor, setCursor] = useState(0);
  const ref = useRef(null);

  const foo = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
    if (e.nativeEvent.data === "$") {
      setShow(true);
    } else {
      setShow(false);
    }
    setCursor(e.target.value?.length*8)
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input value={value} onChange={foo} ref={ref}  />
      {show && (
        <div
          style={{
            width: "200px",
            height: "200px",
            background: "gray",
            marginLeft: cursor + "px",
            position: "absolute",
            left: "0px"
          }}
        >
          DropDown
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: How about calling `setCursor(Math.min(e.target.value?.length, 22)*8)`? It always takes 22 if input has more than 22 characters

Comment: yes its applying perfectly